# Sanitize url path with regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to sanitize a url path from the following elements

- ids (1, 14223423, 24fb3bdc-8006-47f0-a608-108f66d20af4)
- filenames (things.xml, doc.v2.final.csv)
- domains (covered under filenames)
- emails (foo@bar.com)

Sample:

```
/v1/upload/dxxp-sSy449dk_rm_1debit_A_03MAY21.final.csv/email/foo@bar.com?who=knows
```

Desired outcome:

```
/upload/email
```

I have something that works... but I'm not proud (written in Ruby)

```rb
# Remove params from the path (everything after the ?)
route = req.path&.split('?')&.first
# Remove filenames with singlular extentions, domains, and emails
route = route&.gsub(/\b[\w-]*@?[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\b/, '')
# Remove ids from the path (any string that contains a number)
route = "/#{route&.scan(/\b[a-z_]+\b/i)&.join('/')}".chomp('/')
```

I can't help but think this can be done simply with something like `\/([a-z_]+)\/?`, but the `\/?` is too loose, and `\/` is too restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think it's better to go with the allow list here, rather than a block list. Seems like it's more predictable to say "we only keep words with letters and underscores".

```rb
# Keep path w/o params
route = req.path.to_s.split('?').first
# Keep words that only contain letters or _
route = route.split('/').keep_if { |chunk| chunk[/^[a-z_]+$/i] }
# Put the path back together
route = "/#{route.join('/')}".chomp('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can remove the parts starting with a `/` and that contain at least a dot or a digit.

Replace the match with an empty string.

```
/[^/\d.]*[.\d][^/]*
```

[Rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/3tr2P7wzQPs3HX)

- `/` Match a forward slash
- `[^/\d.]*` Match 0+ times any char except `/` or `.` or a digit
- `[.\d]` Match either a `.` or a digit
- `[^/]*` Match 0+ times any char except `/`

Output

```
/upload/email
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can use a bit of code to simplify your checks in a similar way you did:

```rb
text = text.split('?').first.split('/').select{ |x| not x.match?(/\A[^@]*@\S+\z|\d/) }.join("/")
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/WdIChN). Note how much this approach simplifies the email and digit checking.

*Details*

- `text.split('?').first` - split the string with `?` and grab the first part
- `.split('/')` - splits with `/` into subparts
- `.select{ |x| not x.match?(/\A[^@]*@\S+\z|\d/) }` - only keep the items that do not match `\A[^@]*@\S+\z|\d` regex: `\A[^@]*@\S+\z` - start of string, any zero or more chars other than `@`, a `@` char, then any zero or more non-whitespace chars and end of string, or a digit
- `.join("/")` - join the resulting items with `/`.